# Correct placement of try/catch block when using non-immediate async/await

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I've been using async/await for 6 months and been loving the syntactic sugar. I typically use it the traditional way:

```
try {
  await doSomethingAsync()
}
catch (e) {}
```

Recently I've started experimenting with not awaiting immediately so that i run some extra code in this context before waiting for the async data, like:

```
let p = doSometiongAsync()
... do more stuff
await p;
```

or:

```
let p1 = doJob1();
let p2 = doJob2();
... do more synchronous stuff ...
await p1;
await p2;
```

The question is, where is the correct placement of the try/catch blocks to make sure errors (either synchronous or asynchronous) within the calls are caught properly. Is it around the initial function call:

```
try {
   let p = doSomethingAsync() 
 } catch(errors) {}
 ... do stuff ...
 await p
```

or try block around the await... or two different try blocks, one for each?

```
 try {
    let p = doSomethingAsync()
 } catch(errors) {}
 ... do stuff
 try {
     await p;
 } catch (evenmoreerrors) {}
```

thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what `doSomethingAsync` is: An `async` function, or a non-`async` function that returns a promise.

#### If it's an `async` function

...you just need the `try`/`catch` around the `await`; an `async` function never throws synchronously (even if the exception is thrown by the initial synchronous portion of it).

Example:

```js
async function foo() {
  // Note this is in the synchronous portion
  console.log("synchronous part of foo");
  if (true) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve();
  });
}

(async () => {
  const p = foo(); // No uncaught error
  try {
    await p;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Caught the error");
  }
})().catch(e => {
  console.log("Failed to catch it!");
});
```

#### If it's a non-`async` function that returns a promise

...then depending on the function, you may need `try`/`catch` in both places, or not, depending on how it's written. If it may throw in its synchronous code, you need `try`/`catch` around that. And you need `try`/`catch` around the `await` in case of promise rejection.

Example of not handling the synchronous part:

```js
function foo() {
  // Note this is in the synchronous portion
  console.log("synchronous part of foo");
  if (true) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve();
  });
}

(async () => {
  const p = foo(); // No uncaught error
  try {
    await p;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Caught the error");
  }
})().catch(e => {
  console.log("Failed to catch it!");
});
```

Example of failing to catch the promise rejection:

```js
function foo() {
  // Note this is in the synchronous portion
  console.log("synchronous part of foo");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject();
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    const p = foo();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Caught the error");
  }
  await p;
})().catch(e => {
  console.log("Failed to catch it!");
});
```

Comment: Did not expect such a full answer with examples included so fast. Thank you! accepted

Comment: @HarryMexican: Glad to help. It was an interesting question. BTW, there was back-and-forth on whether `async` functions should throw synchronously in certain situations (such as an error in default parameter value handling) when they were being defined, but ultimately the decision was to always have that handled via the implicit promise instead.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where would one have followed a design discussion of that nature for JavaScript. Some github repo?

Comment: @HarryMexican: In this case, yes, it was [issue #35](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/issues/35) and then [#60](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/issues/60) in [the proposal's repository](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait). From #60 we can infer (and I've confirmed) that it was in the [July 2015 meeting notes](https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es7/2015-07/july-30.md).

Answer (score 2):

In both cases errors may be occurred, one in the asynchronous call result, and one also can be occurred, if you have some logic before the `return` statement of the asynchronous call, when your function is not `async`. It depends on your logic where to put `try/catch`.

If you know that an error may be only at the asynchronous call, put `try/catch` only at the `await` statement.

Comment: No, an `async` function never throws synchronously, not even if the error is thrown in its synchronous initial code (not even if it's thrown during default parameter value handling, in fact). A non-`async` function returning a promise may, but not an `async` function.

Comment: I mean if you return from a simple function an promise, not from an async function, but before the promise there is an error. So calling the function will throw an error syncrhonously Have edited the answer to make it clear

Comment: Thank you my Armenian friend. I accepted the other answer since he had examples and went into detail about the case of async vs not async. But appreciate the response. upvoted.

Comment: Thank you too. Very glad for you.